# AWS assume role access denied while using SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-iam, assume-role

I am using go sdk to create a new role and assume it. Both are done with same IAM user.
The role trust relationship is as follows:

```
{
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": { "AWS": "<an admin user>" },
        "Action": [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
    }]
}
```

Later when trying to add object to a bucket, I can create a session token, 
but the PutObject operations fails with AccessDenied.
The bucket policy is:

```
{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action":"s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::<name of the bucket>/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the role you are assuming does not grant access to the S3 bucket via the role policies, you'll need to add the role as a principal to the bucket policy.

There's a handy tool here; https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html that helps with generating bucket policies. But it should end up looking like:

```
{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action":"s3:*",
      "Principal": {
          "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::<accountid>:role/<name of assumed role>"]
      },
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::<name of the bucket>/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {}
}
```